# why <main> tag of html is not a sectioning content but <aside> is

Tags: html

I am reading html specifications of whatwg and mdn. It defines 4 sectioning elements: `article`, `aside`, `nav` and `section`, and says they define the scope of footers and headers.

Here is my questions:

1. `aside` has the opposite meaning of `main` and is part of the
   sectioning category, but `main` is only a flowing content and not
   part of outlining of HTML?
2. These tags are not defined for
   footers and headers only but the entire html part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"aside" doesn't have the opposite meaning of "main". both are not used for headers and footers. "main" tag can be used for the whole page content except header and footer and "aside" is used for our sidebars. such as product filter sidebar in our shop.

Answer (score 0):

article, aside, nav, and section Can all be used within a main tag. Main is the is the basically says, hey this is where my primary content is. You could technically have a main tag within a head or footer, if that was where you main content was located. But you can only have 1 main tag. However you can have multiple article, aside, nav, and section tags within a document.

Comment: It should be noted that article, aside, nav, and section tags can also be used in the header and footer as well..